# Why are densities not fields?

Tags: tensor-calculus, density, vector-fields, covariance

I have read (in [Statistical mechanics of lattice system 2: exact, series and renormalization group methods](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=LYvqCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA2&dq=intensive%20variables%20fields&hl=en&sa=X&ei=xgyJVduBDsLfoASYkpCoBg&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=intensive%20variables%20fields&f=false) by D.A. Lavis and G.M. Bell pg 2 ), that intrinsic variables are either fields or densities.  **But why are densities not scalar fields?** Since a density is a scalar valued function that assigns a value to every point in space, it seems to me that it should be a scalar field.

Comment: A mass or energy density $\epsilon=T^{00}$ transforms like a component of a second rank tensor, not like a scalar!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on how the quantity in question transforms. Almost always, densities in the form of "stuff per unit volume" and generally the "stuff" (like a charge) *is* a scalar (a number of things - number of elementary charges), but the volume it is contained in is observer dependent, owing to the Lorentz contraction. Therefore the density is observer-dependent.

If the "stuff" is a Lorentz invariant like charge, then one can form a flux density $\vec{J}$ describing how swiftly this "stuff" flows through elemental areas and the "stuff" density $\rho$ then combines with $\vec{J}$ to become a four-vector $(\rho,\,\vec{J},\,\rho)$ (or $(c\,\rho,\,\vec{J})$ in SI) - this is the four-current if $\rho$ is electric charge density.

So another way to answer your question is that densities are not scalars because they are the $0$-component of a four-vector, or even some other tensor: the co-ordinate free object  corresponding to energy densities is the rank 2 stress-energy tensor.